# Multidimensional variable with Swift

Tags: swift

i have this code in C

```
float var[4][3]={
{0.6,2,0.5},
{0.9,3,0.8},
{3,2,1.2},
{6,2,1},  
};
```

i call this variable with `var[1][1]` and the result is `3`

in Swift i have

```
let var : [[Float]] = [
    [0.6,2,0.5],
    [0.9,3,0.8],
    [3,2,1.2],
    [6,2,1],     
]
```

But i can't call a specific number. 
What's wrong? Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: you can't use `var` as a name because it is a reserved keyword. Use `array` or something like this instead

Comment: I'm sorry "var" is only an alternative name

Answer (score 0):

Just change your variable name from `var`. It's a keyword in Swift.

```
let arr : [[Float]] = [
    [0.6,2,0.5],
    [0.9,3,0.8],
    [3,2,1.2],
    [6,2,1],     
]

print(arr[1][1]) // 3
```